# Saleor Can't Find SECRET_KEY Even Though Python Can Find It

Tags: saleor

When trying to launch Saleor, the following error appears saying that it can't find SECRET_KEY

Stack:

Debian

Python 3.7.4

Saleor (latest as of 7-25-19)

```
:/$ sudo python manage.py migrate
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

...
...

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 178, in **init**
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

I have done

```
:/$ env
```

and see

```
SECRET_KEY=the-secret-key
```

I also entered a python prompt and tried

```
>>> import os

>>> print(os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY"))

the-secret-key
```

So the value appears to be set an accessible, but the system can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sudo -E python manage.py migrate`

The -E flag preserves environment variables with sudo.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify on the previous answer, you need to remember that **environment variables are scoped to a user**.  So when you run a process using `sudo`, the environment variables that *your* user defined will not be available to the superuser (unless you pass the `-E` flag).  Compare the results of running `env` to `sudo env` and you will see different variables and values.

Another common solution to this problem which you may have seen somewhere is to declare the variables in-line when you execute your script, e.g. `sudo SECRET_KEY=xyz python manage.py migrate`